# Angular 7 FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular7, ng-build

My project is big. In the last build I added big chunk of new functionality. Building process giving me this error log.

Changing  `--max-old-space-size=4096` not working for me.

`{ Error: Command failed: ng build --prod --configuration=config --output-path=test --base-href=/test/
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0x8dbaa0 node::Abort() [ng build --prod --configuration=config --output-path=test --base-href=/test/]
 2: 0x8dbaec  [ng build --prod --configuration=config --output-path=test --base-href=/test/]
 3: 0xad83de v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [ng build --prod --configuration=config --output-path=test --base-href=/test/]
 4: 0xad8614 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [ng build --prod --configuration=config --output-path=test --base-href=/test/]
 5: 0xec5c42  [ng build --prod --configuration=config --output-path=test --base-href=/test/]
 6: 0xec5d48 v8::internal::Heap::CheckIneffectiveMarkCompact(unsigned long, double) [ng build --prod --configuration=config --output-path=test --base-href=/test/]
 7: 0xed1e22 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [ng build --prod --configuration=config --output-path=test --base-href=/test/]
 8: 0xed2754 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [ng build --prod --configuration=config --output-path=test --base-href=/test/]
 9: 0xed53c1 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int, v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [ng build --prod --configuration=config --output-path=test --base-href=/test/]
10: 0xe9d636  [ng build --prod --configuration=config --output-path=test --base-href=/test/]
11: 0xeafee7 v8::internal::Factory::NewLoadHandler(int) [ng build --prod --configuration=config --output-path=test --base-href=/test/]
12: 0xf2f4db v8::internal::LoadHandler::LoadFromPrototype(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Map>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSReceiver>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Smi>, v8::internal::MaybeHandle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::MaybeHandle<v8::internal::Object>) [ng build --prod --configuration=config --output-path=test --base-href=/test/]
13: 0xf36d1f v8::internal::LoadIC::ComputeHandler(v8::internal::LookupIterator*) [ng build --prod --configuration=config --output-path=test --base-href=/test/]
14: 0xf3d94c v8::internal::LoadIC::UpdateCaches(v8::internal::LookupIterator*) [ng build --prod --configuration=config --output-path=test --base-href=/test/]
15: 0xf3dffc v8::internal::LoadIC::Load(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Name>) [ng build --prod --configuration=config --output-path=test --base-href=/test/]
16: 0xf42935 v8::internal::Runtime_LoadIC_Miss(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [ng build --prod --configuration=config --output-path=test --base-href=/test/]
17: 0x235e3925be1d`

Comment: Can you share the build command please?

Comment: You need to check pool, Replace pool from 'ubantu-latest' from 'windows-latest'
That solved my issue.

Answer (score 4):

Can you try --max-old-space-size=8192 with the below prod command

```
node --max-old-space-size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --aot=true --optimization=true --source-map=false
```

Answer (score 3):

Add npm command in **package.json** to scripts like below:

"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
**"go": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve",**
.
.

and then in command line or in terminal use **npm run go**

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem is you need to use underscores rather than dashes.

```
--max_old_space_size=4096
```

4096 might not be enough, you can try increasing it to 8192 as suggested.